# как сохранить файлы yii2 advanced из backend в frontend

Tags: php, yii2

дело в том что при загрузке файлов я нахожусь в backend, но скачивание файла происходит в frontend.
controller который находиться в backend'е

```
  public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Materials();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->filekk=UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'filekk');
        $model->filekk->saveAs( 'uploads/files/'.$model->filekk->baseName.'.'.$model->filekk->extension);
        $model->filekk='uploads/files/'.$model->filekk->baseName.'.'.$model->filekk->extension;

        $model->fileru=UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'fileru');
            $model->fileru->saveAs( 'uploads/files/'.$model->fileru->baseName.'.'.$model->fileru->extension);
            $model->fileru='uploads/files/'.$model->fileru->baseName.'.'.$model->fileru->extension;

          $model->fileen=UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'fileen');
                $model->fileen->saveAs( 'uploads/files/'.$model->fileen->baseName.'.'.$model->fileen->extension);
                $model->fileen='uploads/files/'.$model->fileen->baseName.'.'.$model->fileen->extension;

                $model->filech=UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'filech');
                    $model->filech->saveAs( 'uploads/files/'.$model->filech->baseName.'.'.$model->filech->extension);//путь файла
                    $model->filech='uploads/files/'.$model->filech->baseName.'.'.$model->filech->extension;//имя файла
        $model->save();
                    return $this->redirect(['index']);


    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

}
```

он тупо ложит файлы в backend/uploads/files,
а мне нужно что бы он ложил в frontend/uploads/files

Comment: попробуй `@app/frontend/...`

Comment: попробовал не помогло

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно создать алиас в файле common/config/bootstrap.php, примерно так:

```
Yii::setAlias('uploadsDir', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/frontend/wed/uploads');
```

И далее при сохранении указывать этот алиас:

```
$model->filech->saveAs( Yii::getAlias('uploadsDir/')'.$model->filech->baseName.'.'.$model->filech->extension)
```

Плюс небольшие советы:

Проверяйте сохранена ли модель **$model->save();**

```
if( $model->save()){
   return $this->redirect();
}
```

И так же здесь не нужно else:

```
  else {
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Это не ошибка, но красивее без него, просто:

```
 return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
```

Так же можете в common/config/main.php прописать алиас вот так:

```
 'aliases'    => [
    '@bower'      => '@vendor/bower-asset',
    '@npm'        => '@vendor/npm-asset',
    '@uploadPath' => '@frontend/web/uploads',
    '@bannerPath' => '@frontend/web/style/img',
],
```

Comment: failed to open stream: No such file or directory - выводит такую ошибку

Comment: Значит нету папки. Тут нужно дебажить уже Вас

Comment: C:\OpenServer\domains\httpdocs2018\httpdocs/frontend/wed/uploads/sirdaria.xlsx такой путь вроде не нормально

Answer (score 0):

Вот так работает:

```
$this->filech->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@frontend') .'/uploads/files/' . $model->filech->baseName. '.' . $this->filech->extension);
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stackoverflow! Чтобы Ваш ответ был полноценным, опишите, почему так работает, а так, как написал автор вопроса – нет.